# Change Name in Google MailApp

Tags: google-apps-script

I am editing code created by someone else in google app script.  I am trying to change the name in an email from which the email is sent.  I have looked at the MailApp documentation on Google and what others have mentioned here, but it doesn't seem to match up.  The 4th argument is supposed to be an Object that can specify the name.  There are curly braces around all parts.   I have tried making the changes but nothing works. Here is the code:

```
MailApp.sendEmail({
    "to":studentEmailAddress,
    "cc":parentsEmailAddress,
    "subject":subject,
     "htmlBody":html.getContent()
});
```

Here is what I found on the Google documentation, but it doesn't match up.

```
MailApp.sendEmail('mike@example.com', 'Attachment example', 'Two files are attached.', {
    name: 'Automatic Emailer Script',
    attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF), blob]
});
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Google appscript sends emails from the account of the owner of the script. If you want to change the sender's email then you can change who owns the script, or make a new one within the correct account.